# MS Word table - The requested member of the collection does not exist

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have searched this forum and found several articles related to the same error message. Yet, none is related to my problem.

I have a table in Word with the following properties:

```
wddoc.tables(1).Rows.Count : 15 
wddoc.tables(1).Columns.Count : 4
```

I was trying to copy the table to Excel using the following code:

```
For m = 1 To 15
For l = 1 To 4
ActiveSheet.Cells(m, l) = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(m, l)
Next l
Next m
```

The code worked fine for the first three rows but when it came to the fourth row (m=4, l=1), it threw the titled error message. What gives?

Comment: Don't copy to excel. Copy to an array then copy the array in one go to excel.  Do you have any merged cells in your word table?.

Comment: @freeflow Good thought. There are no merged cells but there is a split cell. How to handle this?

Comment: By the way, that split cell is on row 3 column 2. I actually don't use Word so much to tell whether it is really a split cell. I guess it's a split cell because its row height is half of the other cells. That cell looks like having two half-height cells in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct results from a Word table with merged or split cells, use code like:

```
Dim wdCell As Object
For Each wdCell In wddoc.Tables(1).Range.Cells
  With wdCell
    ActiveSheet.Cells(.RowIndex, .ColumnIndex) = .Range.Text
  End With
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle different numbers of cells in each row, say from splits or merges, with something like this:

```
For m = 1 To wdDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Count
    For l = 1 To wdDoc.Tables(1).Rows(m).Cells.Count
        ActiveSheet.Cells(m, l) = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(m, l)
    Next l
Next m
```

And then to clean things up a little

```
With wdDoc.Tables(1)
    For m = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For l = 1 To .Rows(m).Cells.Count
            ActiveSheet.Cells(m, l) = .Cell(m, l)
        Next l
    Next m
End With
```

Hope that helps